# Where is The Cave of Ordeals located?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

Can anyone out there help me locate The Cave of Ordeals in *The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess*?

Answer (score 6):

> The Cave of Ordeals entrance is found in the Gerudo Mesa where the missing piece of the Bridge of Eldin used to be.

Source: [Zeldapedia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Cave_of_Ordeals)

Comment: Bah, beat me to it!